# which [Node Require] is the right way to use and why?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, require

While importing node package 'cluster', i have used both of the following options and worked fine, which one should be used and what would be the benefit and issue on not using it?

1. require('cluster')
2. require('node:cluster')